# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 126: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, xml, csv, encode

Okay, I have read through many similar questions, and I believe I am following the advice correctly, but somehow my code is still not working.

I have parsed an xml file. I have read on here that the output is now unicode. I am using the csv writer to write output to a file.

So, in my code I have tried to encode in utf-8 before using writerow. Why do I still get the error on writerow? My warning, "unicode!!!" does not get thrown until this error happens (I am running this on multiple files, and it works for most). Actually, though, I don't understand why the writerow is trying to use ascii, shouldn't it be expecting utf-8? I have replaced utf-8 with ascii in the encode function just for kicks. Same results. Please help!!!

```
        try:

           mystring=elem.find('./'+r2+'Description').text


           if isinstance(mystring, unicode):
               print("unicode!!!")
               mystring.encode('utf-8','ignore')
               datalist.append(mystring)
           else:    
               datalist.append(mystring)
        except AttributeError:
           datalist.append('No text')  

        c.writerow(datalist)
```

Comment: "I have parsed an xml file. I have read on here that the output is now unicode." Show how you parse the XML.

Answer (score 9):

When you call `mystring.encode(...`, it's not changing the string in-place; it returns a new string.

Comment: What is the new string called?

Comment: Oh snap, mystring2=mystring.encode(...) then append mystring2 works! Thanks!

Comment: It's not called anything; it's a return value. The reason is that (a) strings (both Unicode and byte-strings) are immutable; (b) even if they weren't, those are two different types, so a Unicode string can't just transform into an encoded byte-string in place.

Comment: Okay, got it. Really appreciate the simple tip!